# Grafana startup error by docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, prometheus

I tried to install [dockprom](https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom) but grafana doesn't come up.The config is not changed at all.

In browser i get this issue : 502 Bad Gateway

and docker container logs are:

```
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied"
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied"
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied"
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied"
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied"
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied"
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied"
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied"
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied"
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied"
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "permission denied"
```

Comment: What's your environment? Where are you trying to start?

Comment: it works fine for me with docker `18.03.1-ce`

Comment: Its Dev environment
Docker version 1.13.1
docker-compose version 1.10.0-rc2

Comment: Both of them are pretty old, can you try with the latest?

Comment: indeed, but there are other tools working as well. so cant upgrade. Kindly can you suggest some other solution.

Comment: worked for me too, did you start the compose with the right env var?: ADMIN_USER=admin ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin docker-compose up -d

Comment: @Ivthillo yes i did with env variables. i also tried setting userid but facing same issue

Comment: Some extra information:Tried some crude way.Promethus runs on on http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000/ so i tried modifying in Prometheus.json the url to ttp://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000/ from "url":"http://prometheus:9090" even that didnt work.